# Cognito sign in verification email not getting username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have set up cognito but the email verification page is not getting my username properly (printing placeholders).

My cognito settings as follows[image]

and the verification email that I received is as follows:
[image]

Do I have to use custom lambda triggers for this? (How do I achieve that)

**Update:** Use **"event.userName"** to get the username in the lambda trigger

```
if(event.triggerSource === "CustomMessage_ForgotPassword") {
            // Ensure that your message contains event.request.codeParameter. This is the placeholder for code that will be sent
            event.response.smsMessage = "You requested to reset your password " + event.request.codeParameter;
            event.response.emailSubject = "You requested to reset your password: " + event.userName;
            event.response.emailMessage = 'Hi, Username:' + event.userName+' , '+ event.request.codeParameter + ' is your verification code '  ;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently many placeholders don't work in simple email verification. You can use custom message lambda triggers to customize the message dynamically. Their documentation has code example for node.js. You can use that to write your own code.

Here's the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html